# Caused by MalformedParameterizedTypeException: null

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm new in using grails programming. 
Actually, I'm upgrading my project that using grails 1.1 to 2.2.4. 
My project have no errors, but I cannot run my project. 
After I run command grails run-app, an error appear in console.

```
Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Running Grails application
| Error 2014-02-08 18:57:43,453 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
Message: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   619 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MalformedParameterizedTypeException: null
->> 794 | getGenericInterfaces in java.lang.Class
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . .  in     ''
^   619 | run      in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2014-02-08 18:57:43,485 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
Message: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   619 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MalformedParameterizedTypeException: null
->> 794 | getGenericInterfaces in java.lang.Class
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . .  in     ''
^   619 | run      in java.lang.Thread
```

This is my BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

// uncomment (and adjust settings) to fork the JVM to isolate classpaths
//grails.project.fork = [
//   run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256]
//]

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
        runtime 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.2.8'
    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        runtime ":resources:1.2"

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"

        compile ':cache:1.0.1'
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to fix this errors?

Comment: which jdk are you using?

Comment: jdk 1.6 and I also try using 1.7 but same error still exist.

Comment: try stripping the dependencies / plugins off, make the project run. Then start adding them back one by one, and see when the exception occurs again...

Comment: Also check you've removed any dependencies from `application.properties` (where deps used to be specified but are now in `BuildConfig.groovy`).

Comment: @injecteer, after plugins off and add them back one by one, i got this error in one of my controller. Internal compiler error: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: grails/plugin/cache/compiler/CacheTransformation : 
 Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
When compile the code, this error appear in console Error Fatal error during compilation java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToCollectionConverter.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/convert/ConversionService;)

Comment: so, either upgrade the cache plugin to `compile ":cache:1.1.1"` or simple remove it if you don't need it

Comment: @injecteer, Thank you. I remove compile ':cache:1.0.1', the error is resolved. Now still got 1 error to resolve. Error Fatal error during compilation java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToCollectionConverter.<init>(Lorg/‌​springframework/core/convert/ConversionService;)

Comment: try upgrading `runtime ":resources:1.2.1"` unless you are using `org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToCollectionConverter` in your code directly

Comment: I've found the "best" (I won't say easiest) way to convert Grails projects between major versions is to create a new project using the new version (make sure it runs), then copy code in from the old project (Domains, Controllers, views, etc.).

Comment: @Bill James, yes it's true. It's not easy and it's tedious too but it's work.